# java rabbitmq unbinding from queue or a Round Robin Exchange

Tags: java, queue, rabbitmq

I have a declared a queue as such:

```
    channel.queueDeclare(name, true, false, true, null);
```

3 clients are bound to that queue ( I called the above declaration 3 times on 3 seperate clients)

How would I unbind a specific client from that queue?

I know it's possible to do so with an exchange, but is it possible with only a queue declaration?

I prefer not to switch to an exchange because I want to implement the Round Robin algorithm. Is it possible to do so with an a exchange?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do *round robin* using *exchanges*. It's most commonly done with **direct** *exchange* routing.

*Exchanges* are meant to work with *queues*, so there shouldn't be any reason you couldn't add those into the mix and still use a *round robin* style approach.

The *RabbitMQ* doc defines *exchanges* thusly:

> Exchanges are AMQP entities where messages are sent. Exchanges take a
>   message and route it into zero or more queues. The routing algorithm
>   used depends on the exchange type and rules called bindings

[More info](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html)